# Suggested way to Map an Object array to Array of Ids

Tags: javascript

If given an array of ids `[1,2,3,4,5]`

And an object array:

```
[{animal:tiger, id:1}, {animal:"fish", id:2}]
```

What would be the suggested way to return `'tiger, fish'`. Would that be through using .map or would a for loop be better for constructing the sentence?

Comment: Please be more precise in your usage of quotes and what exactly you expect. The result you ask for is a `string`, not an `array`; in `{animal:tiger, id:1}` `tiger` is a variable, not a `string`.

Comment: In my opinion, it's always better to use built-in functions because it's often the "safest" way

Comment: @connexo yes, i'm looking for a concatenated string as a result

Comment: The result of *mapping* (see your question title)  is always an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is just go through the list of ids and find corresponding animal in the animals list.

Note, that in case animals list is not expected to store all the animals and some of them are missing, you will need to add additional `filter` step to be sure that no `undefined` values appear on the last `map` step.

```js
const ids = [1,5,2,4,3,6]; // added 6 which is missing in animals
const animals = [
  {name:'Tiger',id:1},
  {name:'Horse',id:2},
  {name:'Mouse',id:3},
  {name:'Elephant',id:4},
  {name:'Cat',id:5}
];

const result = ids
                .map(id => animals.find(a => a.id === id))
                .filter(Boolean) // this will exclude undefined
                .map(a => a.name)
                .join(',');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah this is the nice way to go. Maybe filter for missing elements since the question contains them :)

Comment: instead of mapping it twice you can write `.name` at the end `.map(id => animals.find(a => a.id === id).name)` so you can get rid of `.map(a => a.name)`

Comment: @Ifaruki unfortunately I can't, because if animal wasn't found in the list `find` will return `undefined`, which of course doesn't have "name" property.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov yes. optional chainging should handle this `?.`

Comment: @Ifaruki yes, it will work. But at the moment optional chaining is stiil on a proposal stage to ecmascript. Moreover it is not supported by all platforms/browsers at the moment, so it  is better to not include it in the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = [1,2,3,4,5];
var objects = [{ animal:"tiger", id: 1 }, { animal: "fish", id: 2 }];

objects.map(function(o) { if(ids.includes(o.id)) return o.animal }).join();
```

Comment: In real life you usually find by smaller list of ids in a bigger list of source data. So it is better and more performant to iterate smaller list. 
If animal list will include 1000 animals and id list includes only 3, your code will still iterate all 1000 objects

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing you only want the animal names who's `id` appears in your array. If so, you could `filter` the array of objects first, followed by a `map` and a `join`.

```js
let idarr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let objarr = [{
  animal: "tiger",
  id: 1
}, {
  animal: "fish",
  id: 2
}];

console.log(objarr.filter(x => idarr.includes(x.id)).map(x => x.animal).join(', '))
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest two options, depending on your data & use cases.

## 1. map + find if the animal kingdoms are not too many to loop through.

```
const animals = [
  {animal:tiger, id:1},
  {animal:"fish", id:2}
]

const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

const names = ids.map(id =>
  animals.find(animal => animal.id === id));
```

## 2. convert animals array to object first, for easier frequent access later. One upfront loop, then easier to access by id later.

```
const animals = [
  {animal: "tiger", id:1},
  {animal: "fish", id:2}
]

/*
  Convert
    [{animal:tiger, id:1}, {animal:"fish", id:2}]
  to
    {
      1: { animal: "tiger", id: 1 },
      2: { animal: "fish", id: 2 },
    } 

*/
const animalsObj = animals.reduce((acc, animal) => {
  return {
    ...acc,
    [animal.id]: animal,
  }
}, {});

const ids = [1,2,3,4,5];

const names = ids.map(id => animalsObj[id].animal)
```